# SQL statement to select only row containing max value in one of the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
select * from [Auction].[dbo].[Bids]
```

[image]

I need to select a row with the highest BidValue. When I do

```
SELECT bids.itemId, max(bids.[bidValue]) as HighestBid
FROM [Auction].[dbo].[Bids] bids
WHERE bids.itemId = 2
GROUP BY bids.itemId
```

I get the right row:

[image]

... but when I add two other fields it doesn't work (I know it shows 3 rows because of the Group by, but it throws an error if I don't include those fields in group by):

```
SELECT bids.itemId, max(bids.[bidValue]) as HighestBid, bids.submittedBy, bids.submittedOn
FROM [Auction].[dbo].[Bids] bids
WHERE bids.itemId = 2
GROUP BY bids.itemId, bids.submittedBy, bids.submittedOn
```

[image]

So, I need it do display one row with itemId, HighestBid, submittedBy, and submittedOn.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What DBMS? SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
select TOP 1 * from Bids where ItemId = 2 order by BidValue desc
```

Comment: adding more to your answer for same bidvalue but first one to bid(duplicate bid scenario - its highly unlikely).

SELECT *
FROM [Auction].[dbo].[Bids] bids
WHERE bids.itemId = 2
ORDER BY BidValue Desc, SubmittedOn Asc

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select top 1 * from Bids order by BidValue desc
```

Comment: this will not produce the result that @kate wants.. you should add where clause for item other wise it will give you highest bid of all of the items.

Comment: "I need to select a row with the highest BidValue" - itemId is not mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

if more then one highest value then use

```
select TOP (1) with ties * 
from Bids where ItemId = 2 order by BidValue desc
```